# show div on click with rest of background blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: upload and share dialog]

after reading some questions here , still i m doubtful about how to make a div appear on click on a link like the one in google plus view all friends , when we click on view all then a div appears on the center of the page and rest of background goes blur/opaque . can any one help me with the code , thanks

like here when we click on upload photos a div appear and the background gets little blur

Comment: What you want is called a "lightbox", and is easiest to accomplish using a [lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

Comment: no not a lightbox . i cannot include a full php page inside a lightbox , it does not work , i want it simple like we click on a link a div appears on center of page and rest of the background gets blur

Comment: Yes you can, its a thing called an IFrame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a JSBIN to show you a nice effect:

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owawuq/2/edit)

```
$('.open').click(function(){
  $('#lightbox').fadeTo(1000, 1);
  $("#wrapper").css({'text-shadow': '0px 0px 10px #000'});
});

$('.close').click(function(){
  $('#lightbox').hide();
  $("#wrapper").css({'text-shadow': '0px 0px 0px #000'});
});
```

This is just an idea, now is up to you to play with details!

---

You need:
-a hidden DIV (#lightbox) position:absolute display:hidden that will cover all your page.
To get the initial ~crossbrowser 'blurish' effect just set as a background a white .png 50% transparent.
- to create the blur effect yust made the 'main' text transparent and set an initial '0px' blur:

```
color: transparent;
text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #000;
```

than the jQuery will handle the blur 'togles'.

Comment: wow , u got it right .. it was so cool. but once u click on tht close button the demo does not work again on clicking on the click here

Comment: @Sakshi : You are right. I reedited my demo friend. we had to hide the element once 'close' clicked! (I think that you could easily get the catch too) As I said. Play with the details.

Comment: damn . i was like messed up with how it would work . and boom u solved it . btw ur coding is fast hehe thanks a lot this ends my question but one thing more how can we use load a iframe same way as of that div being loaded

Comment: @Sakshi (Glad it helped!) Just put your iframe / frame inside the `#lightbox_area` !

Comment: no actually i mean to say can we load a iframe on clicking on click here instead of <div id="lightbox"> . u said to put iframe inside the #lightbox_area but i want to load #lightbox_area inside the iframe

Comment: Than you should prepare the overlayed transpartent/white div inside your iframe content. (thank you!)

Comment: m so soory i am so new to this it, thanks for helping out with the demo , if possible can u please explain this also through a demo if possible , thanks for helping out ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5018/discussion-between-roxon-and-sakshi-sharma)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small sample done for you in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/pramodpv/KwzWn/

The working:
When you click the show link, we show a div (in the ex "opacity-provider"), this div is styled to fill the entire screen and some opacity is applied, also its z-index is put such that it is greater than the current data so that it comes on top.

After this the data which you want to show is applied a z-index even greater than the opacity-provider, so this comes over the opaque part.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: best answer without using pluggins or adding a lot of extra code

Comment: thanks for helping through the explanation. it is indeed helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jQueryUI dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

or at fancyform http://www.fancyform.net

There are examples and demos how they work.

Comment: can you re look at the post i have put a image of what i wanted a answer of.

Comment: Niels answered your question. Among the jQueryUI demos, you'll find this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal